# searching email in a text file

Tags: c, file

I have a text file, for example as "file_with_email.txt" which contains following email addresses:

```
crp.edu
src.net
abc.edu
```

I need to search an email in the given text file. the problem with my code is that when I enter the email address with complete domain name , for example,  if I search for example, "abc.edu" then it will return message as "email found", which is correct.

But, in the case I enter the email address with incomplete or partial domain name, for example, "abc.ed", as input which is not contained in the given file, it prints the same output as "email found" even if there is no such email.

Moreover,there are some cases where the emails would be like "abc.edu.net" as input by the user. In that case, my code prints the same output as "email found" which is not contained in the given text file. I would appreciate for any help to fix this problem.

Following is the function for searching email in a text file that I have tried so far:

```
int search_mail(char *email)
{
FILE *fp;
int line = 1;
int number_of_match = 0;
char temp[512];
char *fname = "/home/file_with_email.txt";
    if((fp=fopen(fname, "r"))==NULL)
    {
    return(-1);
    }

    while(fgets(temp, 512,fp) !=NULL)
    {
    fprintf(stdout, "Just read: %s\n", temp);
        if(strstr(temp, email) !=NULL)
        {
        printf("\n The match is found in the file\n ");
        //printf("\n %s \n", temp);
        number_of_match++;
        }
        //line++;
     }

     if(number_of_match == 0)
        printf("\n No result found");

        //close the file if it is open.

     if(fp)
         {
         fclose(fp);
     }
  }
```

Comment: It would help to indent the code properly

Comment: You do not need `if(fp)` as this is always going to be true

Comment: `fprintf(stdout` - `printf` will do

Comment: Why not search for `abc.ed ` - note the final space

Comment: What happens if your string crosses the boundary between successive calls to `fgets()`?

Comment: when I type abc.edu , it returns :match found" but when I write abc.ed to search for, it still shows that match is found. This shouldn't be the case as the twos are different. Even if I search for "abc.edu. net" , it returns match is found.

Comment: @Angela *when I type abc.edu , it returns :match found" but when I write abc.ed to search for, it still shows that match is found.*  Of course it works that way.  When you " write abc.ed to search for", it finds the abc.ed part of **abc.ed**u.  If you want to search for " abc.edu " - note the spaces - you should enter that.  The problem is if you want to search for "abc.edu" delimited by tabs, spaces, newlines, or any other whitespace character at either end.

Comment: This is a completely new question as far as I can see. So I suggest you roll back and open a new question. I think it's pretty rude to just un-accept a months old answer without accepting a better alternative.

Comment: You are right but I  am not able to ask any more question and even not able to delete any question and I really need help on this problem of programming. I am continuously trying to ask questions but it is not allowing me. I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: @Angela there is a reason if you can't ask more questions: you misbehaved to many times (like asking questions and later deleting them or doing other things that are considered rude) and the way you worked with this question is exactly the thing that is considered rude and leads to you being blocked from asking new questions. So now I will roll-back and if you are in desperate need of asking new questions, go to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th and check if anything there helps you.

Comment: Another resource: https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on @grek40's answer, you can search by `mmap()`ing the file on a POSIX-compliant system (note that I left out the appropriate header files and all error checking in order to try and eliminate any scroll bar on the code pane):

```
int startsWithWhitespace = 0;
int endsWithWhitespace = 0;
int fd = open( filename, O_RDONLY );
struct stat sb;
fstat( fd, &sb );
// size + 1 is needed to ensure the mapped file ends with at least one \0 character
char *data = mmap( NULL, sb.st_size + 1, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0 );
close( fd );
char *match = strstr( data, string );
// found a potential match
if ( match )
{
    // check if it's the first char in the file else check the first character *before* the match
    if ( match == data )
    {
        startsWithWhiteSpace = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        startsWithWhitespace = isspace( *( match - 1 ) );
    }
    // get the character one past the end of the matched string
    char *end = match + strlen( string );
    // ensure that the end char is not \0 else the string is at the end of the file
    if ( *end )
    {
        endsWithWhitespace = isspace( *end );
    }
    else
    {
        endsWithWhitespace = 1;
    }
}
...
```

At the end, if `match` is non-null, and both `startsWithWhitespace` and `endsWithWhitespace` are non-zero, the full string has been matched.

Edit: to be thorough, you also need to check the previous and next characters against a list of punctuation marks that you wouldn't consider being part of a longer string.

Assuming you're going to search the file multiple times, this is a perfect use of `mmap()`.  The code to search the file is *simple*, you can treat the file as one long string and not worry about reading parts of it or how to check if a string crosses two successive read buffers.  Searching a huge file will probably be slower than it could be if you really tune the IO operations, but it's so simple and easy it'd probably still the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you basically want to find a string in a way that it is either surrounded by whitespace or is located at the beginning / end of text.

So, what you need is to keep track of the character before the beginning of your searched text and the position of the first character of the possible result. Then, when you have a possible result, check whether it is located at the beginning or the end then check the character before start and after the end with [`isspace(char)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isspace/). You will also need to check for later *real* matches in the string if the first one is a false match (not surrounded by whitespaces).

Another issue with your current approach is, you risk a result starting in the first 512 characters and ending in the next 512 characters. You won't find a result at such a position currently.